# Tableau stacked and side-by-side bar chart on column aggregation

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set like this

`Name     Occupation  Payment   Principal   Interest
Amy          Nurse     100      90            15 
Becky        Teacher   80       100           20 
Catherine    Nurse     90       75            15
John         Engineer  90       80            12
Tom          Teacher   120      100           20
...          ...       ...      ...           ...`

 I'd like to create side-by-side(Payment) stacked chart:

Row: Occupations 
Column1 : stacked(Sum of Interest and Sum of LP Principal) by occupation

Column2 : Only Sum of LP Payment by occupation

Can anyone give me hint how to make it?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not in the correct format for the required chart and you need to do some data prep.

1. Pivot all three measure fields from the data source page.

[image]

2. create a calculation to define the column for each data type

[image]

3. Build the chart as below and hide the header for column field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! But if original measures were gone after pivoting. For instance if I still want to plot a bar chart occupation vs Principal sum how to get data from Principal only?

Comment: @BruceBee, use Pivot Field Names and apply a filter(Only include Principal)

Comment: Yea thanks I think could only do it like this but not quite convenient that I need to rename axis in every plot using these variables. And if I want to create a new calculated field like ratio of Interest to Principal I don't know how to move on further :/

Answer (score 0):

One approach that avoids reshaping your data is to use the measure names and measure values placeholder fields to create the stacked bar chart.

See below
[image]

Comment: sorry but it doesn't seem to be a very good idea since I do need a side-by-side bar chart.

Comment: Then you need only choose “dual axis” for the second measure on the Columns shelf, and then put Measure Names on rows - should also synchronize  axes.